# YA Javascript Regex Question

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to do some javascript form validation through JQuery and a Validation plugin.

I'm doing custom validation rule, with an input value that much match this rule...

```
A-z 0-9 - _ ' & .
```

Basically, I can't figure out the ' & . parts.  Here's what I have now...

```
/^[A-z0-9_]+(-)+$/i
```

...I don't know if that's ideal by any means, it works for what it covers.

But, **what is the best way to do a regex test for the characters above**?  Thanks.

Comment: So that we understand what you want, can you give us a couple input/output examples?

Comment: Do you realize that your `[A-z]` is not doing anything like  what you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match any of your above stated match criteria, any number of times then the following code should work:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9&_.\-']+$/
```

I've included some below test examples noting in the comments when the pattern should be valid or invalid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //A-z 0-9 - _ ' & .
    //valid
    var test_string = "This'Is'-Val1d&_.";
    if (test_string.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9&_.\-']+$/)){
        alert("first test matched");
    }else{
        alert("first test did not match");
    }

    //invalid - whitespace not allowed
    test_string = "This IsNot- Va'l1d & _ .";
    if (test_string.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9&_.\-']+$/)){
        alert("second test matched");
    }else{
        alert("second test did not match");
    }

    //invalid - ! is not allowed
    test_string = "'ThisIsNotValid!'";
    if (test_string.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9&_.\-']+$/)){
        alert("third test matched");
    }else{
        alert("third test did not match");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to have the `-` right after the opening `[` if you want it interpreted literally.

Comment: @justin - and would it be ok to have `-` just before the closing `]` as well?

Comment: @TheDog - Thanks so much! Worked perfectly. I tried something similar, but maybe in the wrong order.  Plus the ' character was screwing up the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio, so I thought it was wrong :-).

Comment: You also need to escape the `.`

Comment: @Justin, I have escaped the - later in the regex.  @Jeff, You do not need to escape the . inside brackets, but normally you would need to escape it.

Comment: @The Dog - Right on both counts; I must not have noticed the backslash at first, unless that was a later edit.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/k3gnM/) what you want?

```
var regex = /^[a-z0-9_\-.'&]/i;
```

Comment: you should include the code as part of your answer too along with the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to escape `.` inside a character class.

Comment: Oh...and don't forget to allow `-` :)

Comment: @Justin man I should really pay more attention to what I'm doing. I'm half watching The Universe and half watching Stack Overflow. Fixing now

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I understand what you're trying to match, but it looks like you want any combination of letters, numbers, or the symbols `-_'&.`. If that's the case, use this:

```
/^[-\w.'&]+$/
```

Note that the `+` could be removed or replaced with `*` depending on how many characters you want to match.

---

Edit - A little explanation of what this means:

- `[-` - When `-` is used at the *beginning* of a character class, it counts as a literal `-`. If it's used inside [] brackets [other than right at the beginning or end of the class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it indicates a range such as `A-Z` or `0-9`.
- `\w` - Matches any letter, any number, or a `_` symbol. This is usually equivalent to  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
- `.'&` - Inside a character class, these have no special meaning other than the literal characters.
- `+` - Means "at least once". You could replace this with `*` if you want to allow an empty string, remove it if you only want one character, or use a quantifier like `{8}`.

[More info at regular-expressions.info.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: I wouldn’t use `\w` to mean `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`: what happens if Javascript ever decides to work on full web data?

Comment: @tchrist That's certainly a valid point; like I said, I had to guess at what the poster is going for. I went for the broader `\w` because it seemed to follow his intent, but it could definitely be replaced by `a-zA-Z0-9_` if he wants to be more strict.

Comment: @Eric - Not really sure what you're getting at with the link, although it's definitely cool to find an online regex visualizer.